# Sqlite3_bind for LIKE statement (Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I try to bind a NSString value into my SQL query but its not working, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my query:

```
Select * from fiche where fichetype = 'EVENT' and sdate like '?%' ORDER BY cdate DESC
```

And I'm using this part of code to bind the value:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(getEventStatement, 1, [value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

This query is working fine in my database but not in Xcode. I also try something else like that:

```
Select * from fiche where fichetype = 'EVENT' and sdate GLOB '?*' ORDER BY cdate DESC
```

This one works in Xcode but all value are display, the ?* is not working.

Anyone? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem with LIKE statement, here is the solution working for me.
first I change my query like that:

```
Select * from fiche where fichetype = 'EVENT' and sdate like ?001 ORDER BY cdate DESC
```

Do not put quotes in the parameter tokens ?001, then create a new strings that put the % into what you are looking for:

```
NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", myValue];
```

Finally, just have to bind the string to the prepared statement like this:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(getEventStatement, 1, [theString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

have fun,